# how to join more than one sqlite tables

Tags: sqlite

I have 7 Sqlite tables and i want to join all these into one table or say a new table .Every tables has same number of column names.I am getting error ambiguity with column name.How can join all these tables.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To avoid ambiguity, you should prefix the columns with the table names and use column aliases:

```
create table tab1(id number, value varchar2(20));
create table tab2(id number, value varchar2(20));
create table tab3(id number, value varchar2(20));

insert into tab1(id, value) values(1, 'a');
insert into tab2(id, value) values(1, 'b');
insert into tab3(id, value) values(1, 'c');

create table t4 as 
  select tab1.id id, tab1.value value1, tab2.value value2, tab3.value value3 
  from tab1, tab2, tab3 
  where tab1.id = tab2.id 
  and tab1.id = tab3.id;
```

Comment: +1 though I think it's better to be explicit about aliasing and write `tab1.id AS id` (instead of `tab1.id id`) as it's just so much easier to see it immediately for what it is.

Comment: @Donal agreed - in production code, I'd also put the select and each of the columns in the select on a separate line, but I was feeling lazy :-)